One country piracy law in another country
Products issued in one country under one copyright while you reside in another bind you to follow the copyright of the first country or if pirating in the country of stay is permitted it is fine?

I suspect we need to know some more information to answer this; the type of information that should ideally be included in the question so people don't have to go researching it, i.e. the actual law in this case. Perhaps ask on law.SA first?

The corporate law requires that one be compliant according to laws of both countries. They even require all corporate workers to take webinars where this point is emphasized in many different ways.
